# Where is stored a backup database in Azure Data Studio?

Tags: sql-server, docker, macos

I want to access my backup database out of the Data Studio, however I am not finding the located file used to backup (e.g. /var/opt/mssql/data/database.bak). I am using a docker container and I stored inside that container on my local machine (CONTAINERID:/tmp). I don't know why I can't find any of those location. I am in a macOS Monterey 12.6.2 if that is relevant.

Comment: How did you make the backup in the first place?

Comment: In my local server I hover over the database I wanna do the backup right click, only changed the location where I wanna store.  Everything was set by default.

Comment: And what was the location you set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was, since I knew the location, export the database out of docker container `docker cp CONTAINERID:/tmp/database.bak ~/location`, however I still in trouble to find the location 'CONTAINERID:/tmp/database.bak' in the command line.